# How can I know entrypoint or cmd to enter inside a kubernetes pod using kubectl?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am learning kubernetes right now.I want to enter a pod which is in remote cluster . But, I don't know it's entrypoint. I can't find it using **$kubectl describe pod podname**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the shell in a Container(POD), You can use the following command.

```
kubectl exec POD -c CONTAINER -- COMMAND [args...]
```

For example, IF the Pod has bash shell, you can access it with the following command.

```
kubectl exec -it shell-demo -- /bin/bash
```

You will be able to access the shell

> root@shell-demo:/# ls /

Here is the reference [get-shell-running-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But, How would I know /bin/bash is the entrypoint or cmd?

Comment: Hi, If I am not misunderstood, are you referring to docker terminology here?.  In kubernetes, you need to check argument of the container.

Comment: ok..I am actually new to both of them. I know that, if I want to know entrypoint of a container for docker, it is possible by "$docker container inspect container-name". or "$docker image inspect image-name". Is there any similar command available in kubernetes?

Comment: I would suggest you not to mix terminology with docker and kubernetes. As they work in different level of abstractions. you might be more confused.

Comment: I think this doesnt answer to OPs question. OP means to see the entrypoint/ CMD of the image that the pod runs. As mentioned previously, checking the command field in kubectl describe pod gives that.

Comment: @DeekshithAnand good catch. I should have mentioned to use ps command to list all the flags.  if you know other way, you could edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint for the container (there can be multiple per pod but asummuing just one in this case) can be seen in it's docker definition. You can either check the Dockerfile that generated it or in case you don't have it just pull the image and inspect the content. For example with a mongoDB image:

```bash
docker pull docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.2-debian-11-r1
docker inspect docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.2-debian-11-r1 | grep -A1 Entrypoint
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/bitnami/scripts/mongodb/entrypoint.sh"
```

That being said a more practical approach (borrowed from the Lens k8s client) is to just brute force it and try with as many shells as you can think of for example:

```
kubectl exec -i -t -n <InsertNamespaace> <InsertPodName> -- sh -c "clear; (bash || ash || sh)"
```