# Command and args in pod

Tags: kubernetes

There are many way to set command in pod.

```
1.
command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 1000"]
2.
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c","sleep 1000"]
3.
args:  ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 1000"]
```

Are they the same or different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all almost the same; except that if the underlying image has a Docker `ENTRYPOINT` then the `args:` are passed to it as arguments in the third case, without `command:`.

In core Docker, there are two ways to specify the main container command, the Dockerfile [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) directives.  Either or both of these can be overridden when the container starts, but resetting the `ENTRYPOINT` value always clears `CMD`.  If both are present then [the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

Kubernetes has the same concept and uses the same underlying image structure, but its names are different:

- Kubernetes `command:` overrides Docker `ENTRYPOINT` (and resets `CMD`)
- Kubernetes `args:` overrides Docker `CMD`

So in the first case setting `command:` overrides the container entrypoint and resets the container command to an empty list; in the second you directly set both parts.  In both cases the two lists are combined together and you get an identical 3-word command.

In the last case `args:` only overrides the container command part.  If the image has a Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` then this list of arguments is passed as arguments to the entrypoint process.

Which one is "right" depends on how the image is constructed:

- Some images use `CMD` to specify the main command to run and don't have `ENTRYPOINT`; in this case any of the forms you show will work.

  ```bash
  CMD the-main-program
  # override with either Kubernetes command: or args:
  ```
- Some images use `ENTRYPOINT` to specify the main command to run (and depending on how they're constructed may completely ignore `CMD`).  In this case you must use one of the first two forms with `command:`.

  ```bash
  ENTRYPOINT ["the-main-command"]
  CMD ["--argument", "value"]
  # override with Kubernetes command: and optionally args:
  ```
- Some images use `CMD` to specify the main container command, and `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script to do first-time setup.  In this case you need the third form that sets only `args:` or else the entrypoint script will get skipped.

  ```bash
  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
  CMD ["the-main-command"]
  # override with Kubernetes args: only
  ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384481/how-can-i-know-entrypoint-or-cmd-to-enter-inside-a-kubernetes-pod-using-kubectl

Comment: That is my question too. how do I know entrypoint of image?

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple args in a Helm template you need to add them in separated lines. I even added a whitespace, IIRC that was needed for sure:

```
           args:
             - "--arg1"
             - " --arg2"
```